# How to get first or guardian actor in akka.net?

Tags: akka.net

Edit : Executive summary: Where the bleep is 'Sys' defined? I see it in Akka.net code all over the internet, but my build is not finding it. Who or what do I have to import, use, link, do, bribe or kill?

Should be screamingly easy. Taking first steps in Akka.net, the sample does not build. This was copied from the [Getting Started example][1]

[1]: https://getakka.net/articles/intro/tutorial-1.html . It does not build, because 'Sys' is not defined. This obviously elementary step is nowhere described on their site, and I've given up on tweak-n-try.

Here is all of the code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyAkka
{
    class Program
    {
        public class PrintMyActorRefActor : UntypedActor
        {
            protected override void OnReceive(object message)
            {
                switch (message)
                {
                    case "printit":
                        IActorRef secondRef = Context.ActorOf(Props.Empty, "second-actor");
                        Console.WriteLine($"Second: {secondRef}");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            var firstRef = Sys.ActorOf(Props.Create<PrintMyActorRefActor>(), "first-actor");
            Console.WriteLine($"First: {firstRef}");
            firstRef.Tell("printit", ActorRefs.NoSender);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version of your code:

```
using System;
using Akka.Actor;


namespace SysInAkkaNet
{
    class Program
    {
        public class PrintMyActorRefActor : UntypedActor
        {
            protected override void OnReceive(object message)
            {

                switch (message)
                {
                    case "printit":
                        IActorRef secondRef = Context.ActorOf(Props.Empty, "second-actor");
                        Console.WriteLine($"Second: {secondRef}");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            using (var actorSystem = ActorSystem.Create("MyActorSystem"))
            {
                var firstRef = actorSystem.ActorOf(Props.Create<PrintMyActorRefActor>(), "first-actor");
                Console.WriteLine($"First: {firstRef}");
                firstRef.Tell("printit", ActorRefs.NoSender);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

You need to create an actor system to put your actors in. And you need to add a reference to the Akka NuGet package, and a corresponding `using Akka.Actor;` statement.

I know that the Akka.TestKit has a property `Sys`, which gives you a reference to the actor system that is created for a given test.

Apart from that, I am not able to answer why the documentation you are referring to shows these "Sys.ActorOf(...)" examples like that (with a capital S), indicating that it is a (possibly built-in) property, so I kind of understand your confusion there.